# How to identify a place in Google Maps API, with id or reference?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

With the Places Autocomplete i can get the same place with different names (mostly changing the Bound). I save the place in my DB. I need to identify the place, wathever name has been introduced. Two values are candidats: `id` and `reference`. But, according to documentation, both values can change!

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=en#place_details_responses

How can i identify a place?

Comment: Why don't you use `place.geometry.location`?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici That's a good one! I'll try! Thanks!

Comment: Have you found any other solutions?

Comment: @MikhailSP No. I took this one and works. It's a little tricky, because you have to pass two values to get one place, but works.

Answer (score -1):

Yes both can change, but the refId will also point to the same place.  For some reason you can have many refIds to one place.  Only be weary about the id.

reference contains a token that can be used to query the Details service in future. This token may differ from the reference used in the request to the Details service. It is recommended that stored references for Places be regularly updated. Although this token uniquely identifies the Place, the converse is not true: a Place may have many valid reference tokens